# Can ubsan catch launder

Tags: c++, ubsan, stdlaunder

I am considering the transmorgify example on cppref (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder). In the comments they mention that a second call to `transmorgify` would invoke undefined behaviour

```
// int m = base.transmogrify(); // undefined behavior
```

Does there exist a compiler (with a suitable sanitization option) that captures this ub? More generally in the range of examples given for the use case of `std::launder` does some ubsan tool expose the ub?

I have run both g++ and clang with sanitize flags and didn't get any runtime errors

Comment: Unlikely. `std::launder` is purely compile-time. With optimzations off, a code written with and without `std::launder` is likely to produce exactly the same assembly. That would make it impossible to detect at runtime.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Technically, `std::launder` exists as an annotation for the compiler _not_ to compile to the same assembly as that would be incorrect in the cases where it's UB without `std::launder`. But I'm not aware of cases where compilers actually uses `std::launder`.

Comment: @PasserBy I agree that you are technically correct, but in practice the annotation has little effect especially when optimization is off, as you have stated.

Comment: Well the example given in cppref produces different assembly but that is not really the point as I am not asking to tell if std::launder has been called but if a ubsanitizer can find the ubs if it were not called - the specific case on cppref gives an example of one of the cases I am looking at

Comment: It's UB caused by interpreting an address as an invalid type. Those are difficult to catch unless we have type annotations to memory or run into cases which `object-size` can handle. It is as difficult as catching UB by `reinterpret_cast`, I would say.

Comment: In order to detect UB like that it would be necessary to track a lot more state for each object. To me it doesn't seem to be possible in a practical way.

Comment: @PasserBy Here's the only example I know: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder#Example